# Именованные константы в Python

Tags: python, константа

Есть ли в Python константы? В книге столкнулась с понятием "именованные константы". Слышала в прошлом году, что константы в Python отсутствуют.

Comment: https://pythonz.net/references/named/constants/

Comment: постарайтесь подобные вопросы решать с помощью официальной документации и справочных ресурсов.

Comment: Python Constants:  https://realpython.com/python-constants/

Comment: СПАСИБО ВСЕМ ЗА ПОМОЩЬ!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько мне известно, в питоне не существует констант. Есть только соглашение именовать переменные ТАКИМ_ОБРАЗОМ, что означает, что менять их значение не следует.

Comment: СПАСИБО БОЛЬШОЕ!

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать модуль `Constant`:

```
from pyconst import Constant

const = Constant()
const.PI = 3.14159
```

Более подробная информация есть [здесь](https://fullstacker.ru/rabotaem-s-konstantami-v-python)

Comment: Кто же это поставил плюс коду, который 1. падает с ошибкой, 2. отвечает на какой-то другой вопрос?..

Answer (score 0):

«Настоящие» константы, т.е. такие, которые

1. **явно** определяются как константы (напр. в языке C/C++ ключевым словом `const`),
2. и которым должно присвоить какое-то значение **прямо в их определении**,
3. и которым язык программирования (точнее их компилятор / интерпретатор / система во время исполнения) **не позволит** изменить их значение, хотя бы программист этого хотел (т.е. попытка это сделать вызовет **ошибку**

в Питоне действительно **не существуют**.

Вместо этого в Питоне программист **сам** должен следить за тем, чтобы то, что бы он хотел сохранить как константу, невольно не изменил.

Чтобы программист не выл должен помнить / думать, если ту или другую переменную он хочет считать константой, в Питоне [принято для констант использовать имена со всеми буквами **прописными**](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pep-8-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-koda-na-python.html#section-29), например **`GREEN`**, **`PLAYER1`** или **`FIRST_NUMBER`**.

Для опытного программиста в Питоне такие имена являются **«неприкосновенными»** — он их будет только использовать, но не менять.

---

*Примечание:*

Константы в языках программирования используются главным образом для избежания от «[магических чисел](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5))» - например в долгой программе вы встретитесь с командой

```
for i in range(36):
```

и сразу же не поймете, почему там именно число `36`.

Но когда вы это число определите — лучше всего в начале программы — как константу с соответствующим именем, все становится ясным:

```
ORDERS = 36                      # количество заказов (в начале программы)
   ...
   ...
for i in range(ORDERS):
       ...
```

Comment: если быть точным, то в python, есть 4 "настоящие константы". Это True, False, None и \_\_debug__. [ссылка](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html)

Comment: @Danis, если быть точным, то вы правы, да. Но это не константы, которые соответствуют моим пунктом **1** и **2**, т.е. не константы, которыми управляет программист. Я думал, что именно такие констатны интересовали ТС, но я должен признать, что в вопросе такого ограничения не было. Так что еще раз, вы правы. Спасибо вам за комментарий.